# Drawer like Google material design for iOS

Tags: ios, material-design, navigation-drawer, drawertoggle

I'd like to implement navigation drawer like Uber into iOS(swift). I'm going to achieve it by using a library, called KYDrawerController. https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController

However, it cannot provide toggle button, only slide action. Thought I'd like to to implement toggle button that shows the navigation drawer,I have no idea how to add such a function to the library.
If you know how to add the function to the library, or how to achieve my purpose the other way(such as to use the other libraries), please tell me.
Thank you for your kindness.

[image: Uber1]
[image: Uber2]

Comment: what toggle button, are you referring to the button that shows the navigation drawer

Comment: Yes. The button that shows the drawer

Comment: so why not adding a UIBarbutton that will call the slide action, never used that library. I have used this one https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController and it can do what your looking for

Comment: In general you'll notice Apple themselves never use a drawer (aka hamburger menu) UI. (Perhaps someone can find a example?) As a thought experiement, you might try to imagine a tab bar-based interface that provides the same features.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain enough. I want to make drawer menu slide over  the main view, not push the main view.
I've achieve the latter view by MMDrawerController https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController, but I'd like to change it.

Comment: follow up: I saw this linked on hacker news today: http://deep.design/the-hamburger-menu/

Comment: haha, it criticizes a hamburger menu. Thank you for your advice:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [KYDrawerController](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController/) it can be implemented as follows:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        title = "MainViewController"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Open",
            style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
            target: self,
            action: "didTapOpenButton:"
        )
    }

    func didTapOpenButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let drawerController = navigationController?.parentViewController as? KYDrawerController {
            drawerController.setDrawerState(.Opened, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController/tree/master/Example/Code

Comment: Thank you!
In fact, I've found your library then solved the problem. lol
Very good library:)