# Button item not shown in navigationBar embebed in TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, navigationbar

I'm working on an app where a viewController is embebed in navigationBar and this navigationBar is embebed in TabBarViewController.

In my app I have 2 different tabs (for the moment), one tab is the "Activity view". This is a viewController with a tableView where list activities. Every cell will show the same view controller showing detail activity when it's touched.

My problem is that not showing navigationItem with buttons.

I'm trying the solution of: [Bar button item not shown in navigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696523/bar-button-item-not-shown-in-navigationbar) , because my problem is very similar but it did not work.

some screenshots of storyboard and app running:
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQPcV.png)
[App running without buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQnUm.png)

I'm trying programmatically add buttons but no results:

```
var logoutButton: UIBarButtonItem!
var filterButton: UIBarButtonItem!


//MARK: - Lyfe cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let logoutImage = UIImage(named: "logout-24")
let filterImage = UIImage(named: "filterOutline-24")

logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: logoutImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "logoutAction:")
filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: filterImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "filterAction:")
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [filterButton, logoutButton]
```

Comment: I tried several ways to work the SPLITVIEW as a side menu but did not succeed. So I looked for other ways to perform the desired result. So I found a side Menu [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930585/drawer-like-google-material-design-for-ios) the github [github](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController) which soon time got the expected result. Including tabbar and their respective sailings. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For tabar application we should add like this,

```
 let logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_logout"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(logoutButtonTapped))    
 self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton

 let nightModeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_night_mode_off"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(nightModeButoonTapped))
 self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = nightModeButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your image. I don't see any problem with your code. Or you can try add just title like below

```
logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log out", style: .Plain, target: self, action:Selector("logoutAction:"))
filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filter", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector("filterAction:"))
```

If button bar show. I sure that problem is your image.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. The button is still not showing.  I think it has to do with the navigationItem not showing, but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: the previous version (without tabbar) show the buttons, but when I add the tabBar this buttons not showing... [link](http://i.imgur.com/1QymvGs.png) , [link](http://i.imgur.com/dDThJ1s.png). I need add tabBar for other views... :/

Comment: can you check your navigationItem it nil or not?

Comment: interesting... how I can check my navigationItem it nil? 
part of my viewDidLoad:
`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        
        if let contract = detailContract {
            navigationItem.title = contract.Name
            loadActivities(contract)
        }
    }
`

Comment: you print print(navigationItem) in your viewdidload.

Comment: my print was: <UINavigationItem: 0x7fa969cf0730>

Comment: I forgot to add a segue in splitView: [new Storyboard](http://i.imgur.com/e6Bhxyd.png) .  Now appears buttons :)  
But no back button [app running](http://i.imgur.com/sdBsusu.png)....how add back button to masterViewController (from SplitViewController...)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem, later I found that set up your navigation bar in tab bar controller itself, no need to do in view controllers

```
let profilePutton = UIButton(type: .custom)
profilePutton.setTitle("Profile", for: .normal)
profilePutton.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
profilePutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openProfilePage), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profilePutton)
```